# Convert Tuple to Array in F# and Xamarin

Tags: ios, f#, xamarin

I have a call to AddSubviews which is defined as `AddSubviews(views: UIView[])`which means it gets an array of UIViews. Then I have a call to that method like `this.View.AddSubviews (a, b, c)` which is as far as I can say a call that has a tuple as its sole parameter.

Now somehow this tuple gets converted into an array. But how does this happen?

Comment: May be it uses the Parameter Array http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx (ParamArray attribute)

Comment: F# always does what you want. :-)

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UIView.AddSubviews):

`AddSubviews` is defined like this:

```cs
public void AddSubviews (params UIView[] views)
```

and as such, takes an arbitrary number of arguments and turns them into an array.  This looks like a `Tuple` in F# since un-curried functions look like they take a single tuple as a parameter.

The same definition in F# looks like this:

```ml
member this.AddSubviews([<ParamArray>] views: UIView[])
```